# I need to call a sockets "setopt" routine from kernel space

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, linux-kernel

I need to make changes to a TCP socket (although I'd like to keep it generic) from kernel space. A USB driver will receive a message and need to make this change to a given `socket` struct.

Directly calling the function requires userspace memory and the workarounds are not something I can place in production. So a straightforward call seems unlikely. Another solution I saw was to replicate the portions that expect userspace memory, but this solution is not something I want to put in production either.

I am considering writing a userspace program to talk to the driver via procfs and make the call. The driver would place data in the file to instruct the userspace app to do various things.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the option, you can call [`sock_setsockopt`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/sock_setsockopt) or [`tcp_setsockopt`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/tcp_setsockopt) from within kernel space. There are also functions for [IPv4](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/ip_setsockopt) and [IPv6](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/ipv6_setsockopt) options.

Or, if you just want to manipulate particular options, you can view how these functions are implemented, and then use the same implementation for your particular options. For example, if you wanted to adjust [`TCP_CONGESTION`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/TCP_CONGESTION) directly, `tcp_setsockopt` does this (after validating the passed in values):

```
    lock_sock(sk);
    err = tcp_set_congestion_control(sk, name, true, true,
                     ns_capable(sock_net(sk)->user_ns,
                            CAP_NET_ADMIN));
    release_sock(sk);
```

Comment: `tcp_setsockopt` has a parameter `char __user *optval`. Is there a non-hacky way to create this memory in kernel space? All the workarounds I've seen involve bad practices.

Comment: That is why I suggested you view the option implementations, and do what the implementations do after the memory has been copied. But a more direct answer to your question would be to have a memory map to user space memory available that you copy args into and pass the pointer into that memory map area.

Comment: That's the other thing I was hoping to avoid because I don't know the kernel versions of future customers who will use this. Is this considered an OK practice? I'm worried that I'll implement the procedure on one version and need to change it for a customer on a different version becuase I'm not just calling the function. It seems like a violation of basic encapsulation.

Comment: In the example I cited, `tcp_set_congestion_control` is available in the kernel header `include/net/tcp.h`. So long as you stick to interfaces published under `include`, I don't see any major problems. Any kernel module would have to track kernel changes anyway. The only way to stay relatively immune to kernel changes would be to have your code reside entirely in user space.